# Passing Linux NFS traffic through Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-server-2008, nfs, passthrough

We are developing an embedded device that runs on Linux and uses NFS mounts to aid in development. We are working in two private network spaces (`172.16.x.y` and `192.168.0.n`). The `192` network contains `40Mb/s` multicast traffic that the device needs, but in order not to swamp the `172` network the network traffic is generated by a Windows 2008 R2 Server. The Windows Server 2008 box has 2 NICs - one for `192` (generated from the DHCP server on it) and one for `172` network (the default gateway on the Windows box points to the `172` gateway)

In our development environment we have the following connections:

```
Device 172.16.50.100 (static)]----[Gateway (172.16.15.200)]----[Ubuntu Linux Server 172.16.10.100]
```

The device is able to mount and execute code on the `172.16.10.100` server.

However, when we move the device to the Windows Server network:

```
Device 192.168.0.2(dhcp)]---[Server 2008 (192.16.0.1)(dhcp server) NIC2(172.16.50.200)]---[Ubuntu Linux Server 172.16.10.100]
```

Now the device is unable to mount the NFS directories:

```
\$ mount -t nfs 172.16.10.100:<path> hd
mount: 172.16.10.100:<path> failed, reason given by server: Permission denied
mount: mounting 172.16.10.100:<path> on hd failed: Bad file descriptor
```

We can ping the server:

```
\$ ping -c 1 172.16.10.100
PING 172.16.10.100 (172.16.10.100): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.16.10.100: seq=0 ttl=64 time=1.231 ms

--- 172.16.10.100 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 1.231/1.231/1.231 ms
```

Hence the device can see the Ubuntu server fine when it is on the `192` network, but is unable to mount the NFS.

We have disabled the Windows Server 2008 Firewall as well.

How do we get the NFS data to pass through the server?

Thanks.

Comment: your nfs traffic reaches the nfs server. Check the export file. You server sees client packes coming  from e different IP address and rejects the mount request.

Comment: The exports file is very simple: `/home   *(rw,no_root_squash,async,no_subtree_check)` - This is the only line to export all `/home` directories

Comment: what is the resolt of mount -vvv -t nfs  172.16.10.100:<path> hd

Comment: Unfortunately the version  of busybox we are running does not output anything more `failed, reason given by server: Permission denied`

Comment: It seems like NFS is the only protocol having an issue. TFTP works fine across the link

Comment: try with -o tcp. Can you get a packet capture?

Comment: Using the tcp option make mount "hang" for a very very long time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@tigran - thank you for the help. You raised some very important points.

The problem here was actually port numbers.

In the first scenario:

```
Device 172.16.50.100 (static)]----[Gateway (172.16.15.200)]----[Ubuntu Linux Server 172.16.10.100]
```

The device was requesting:

```
authenticated mount request from 172.16.50.100:709
                                               ^^^
```

However, in the second scenario:

```
Device 192.168.0.2(dhcp)]---[Server 2008 (192.16.0.1)(dhcp server) NIC2(172.16.50.200)]---[Ubuntu Linux Server 172.16.10.100]
```

The Windows Server was changing the port number:

```
refused mount request from 172.16.50.217 for <path> (/home): illegal port 62441
                                                                          ^^^^^
```

According to [Man Help Pages for the export file](http://linux.die.net/man/5/exports):

```
secure
This option requires that requests originate on an Internet port less 
than IPPORT_RESERVED (1024). This option is on by default. To turn it
off, specify insecure.
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Seeing that this is a closed private network, we have updated the `/etc/exports` file to have:

```
/home *(rw,no_root_squash,async,no_subtree_check,insecure)
                                                 ^^^^^^^^
```

For reference, the debug lines come from `/var/log/syslog` after changing `/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server` file to include:

```
RPCMOUNTDOPTS="--manage-gids --debug all"
```